# $K^{1/p}\otimes_K K[[x]] \subseteq K^{1/p}[[x]]$ is a flat extension

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

I'm reading the proof of Kunz theorem, the "easy" part that says a ring $R$ of prime characteristic $p$ being regular implies that the Frobenius map $R\to R, r\mapsto r^p$ is flat. There is a detail saying

"$K^{1/p}\otimes_K K[[x]] \subseteq K^{1/p}[[x]]$ is a flat extension because completion is flat."

Here $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$ and $K^{1/p} $ is the ring containing all the $p$-roots of elements in $K$.

By definition, I can prove that this is indeed an inclusion. But that's it. Why is this extension is exactly the completion?

Comment: The maximal ideal of $K^{1/p} \otimes_K K[[x]]$ is $K^{1/p} \otimes_K (x)$, so the completion is the inverse limit of the $(K^{1/p} \otimes K[[x]]) / (K^{1/p} \otimes_K (x))^n=(K^{1/p} \otimes_K K[[x]])/(K^{1/p} \otimes_K (x^n))=K^{1/p} \otimes_K K[[x]]/(x^n)=K^{1/p}[x]/(x^n)$, and thus said inverse limit is the $x$-adic completion of $K^{1/p}[x]$ so is $K^{1/p}[[x]]$.

Comment: i've been checking the argument and i've still not worked out the last one. I think you want $K^{1/p}\otimes_K K[[x]]/x^n = K^{1/p}\otimes_K K[x]/x^n = K^{1/p}[x]/x^n$. The last one I think the map is just multiplication. But I'm not sure why that is surjective?

Comment: Any polynomial $P=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{u_kx^k} \in K^{1/p}[x]/(x^n)$ is of the form $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{u_k \cdot x^k}$ with $u_k \in K^{1/p}$, $x^k \in K[x]/(x^n)$.

Comment: but the map is multiplication, so to prove that it is surjective the $u_k$ must be equal, right? I mean I don't see a way to extract a common element in $u\in K^{1/p}$ s.t. $P=u(\sum (a_k/u)x^k)$ s.t. each $a_k/u$ is in $K$.